# Using mysql_config_editor

Tags: mysql, windows

Using mysql_config_editor on a computer running Windows 7 pro so password need not be put into batch file

Running MySql version 5.7 on Windows 7 Pro.  I am learning MySql .
My goal is to put the MySql password into a file so I don’t have to put the plain text password into batch files I want to invoke .There is much I do not understand about the relationship between MySql and Windows permissions.

Before executing mysql_config_editor, I would manually navigate to the 
cd “Program Files\Mysql\Mysql Server 5.7\bin    folder
   and then type             mysql
  I would get a prompt for password.  I enter the password and the MySql command prompt appears.

I read about mysql_config_editor.  So I typed:
  mysql_config-editor  set –user=root –password
  The   mysql_config-editor prompted me for a password .  I entered the password.

Then I navigated to the bin folder as above.
  I typed          mysql and this time the mysql command prompt immediately appears, no prompt for password.
  The mysql 5.7 manual says the   mysql_config-editor  will create a file called mylogin.cnf  .  I have searched all the drives on my Windows 7 computer and cannot find this file.  Yes, I am logged in as administrator, I have full rights.

So I thought now, when I execute a Windows batch file,  I just need to enter the –user=root command in the batch file  and MySql will log in as user root without any need for me to provide a password.  And this works as log as I am logged in as administrator.

Question:
 I cannot find any file called mylogin.cnf .  I cannot find any file when I search for mylogin*.*  Obviously the  mysql_config-editor changed something.  What file did it change?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  The mysql_config_editor creates a file named .mylogin.cnf in the administrator roaming profile on a Windows 7 Pro computer.  Notice the dot in front of the file name. However, I don’t log on to my Windows 7 Pro machine as administrator.   I know most people do.  I log in using a standard user account.  Why?  Because then viruses and trojans have more difficulty in infecting my computer.

I start MySql using the standard user account.  The goal was to be able to start a MySql batch job without having to put the password in the batch file.  So I decided to copy the .mylogin.cnf file from the administrator roaming profile to the standard user roaming profile.  And this works!   Now the MySql batch file will log in to the root MySql user without any password present in the batch file.

Comment: Thanks for your research!